# Cakephp, searchable behaviour help, returning empty results

Tags: php, mysql, search, cakephp, indexing

I'm using the [searchable behaviour](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/search-feature-to-cakephp-blog-example) from the bakery.

It is all set up correctly with no errors, so there is no problem there. However when preforming a search it returns no results. I'm at a loss as to why this is happening because of a lack of any errors.

I think it might have something to do with initial set up or the indexing of the search data. Does sql need to index all of the data at the beginning in order to search it or is there a function I can run to make this index? Something like that?

It would be great if someone can help me out with this (it my first time making a search). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current entries in the database needed re-indexing. It was only data added after the behavior functionality was added that showed up in the results. This is actually a pretty good plugin:

http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/search-feature-to-cakephp-blog-example

Answer (score 2):

Not sure, but here's an alternative plugin for adding [search functionality](http://www.neilcrookes.com/2009/11/21/cakephp-searchable-plugin/) to your app

Answer (score 2):

maybe the search function worked will but you didn't know.you know, the search app is based on the sql function "match...against". it seems that if the keyword apprears on more than 50% of the records,then there will be no results.
for example, the post of the original Blog. you can use the data from the refrence of sql.

```
-> ('MySQL Tutorial','DBMS stands for DataBase ...'),
-> ('How To Use MySQL Well','After you went through a ...'),
-> ('Optimizing MySQL','In this tutorial we will show ...'),
-> ('1001 MySQL Tricks','1. Never run mysqld as root. 2. ...'),
-> ('MySQL vs. YourSQL','In the following database comparison ...'),
-> ('MySQL Security','When configured properly, MySQL ...');
```

then search for 'database', then you can find 2 record

hope this can help you